# How to develop resizable Interactive Board In Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create the board like below numbers.it should be in the HTML,css,Actually purpose of this board is to display 49 numbers on board and board should be re sizable in any window.main use of this board is in mobile device and each row display 1 to 10 fix numbers as such.please help me and don't use table tag.only div element should be there.

1  2  3  4  5  6 7 8  9 10

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any code you have written?

Comment: Do **you** want to create the board? It looks like you want someone else to create it for you. Have you tried anything? Post the code of your attempts.

Comment: Man, I've replied to several question today and as soon as they get what they want, they just vanish without giving any feedback...

Comment: @chadocat Chances are if they don't show the smallest amount of effort in their question, they're not going to hang around to reward/provide feedback to those that spent time helping them. Best off just asking 'what have you tried' if they've shown no effort. It quickly filters out those that want help from those that just want the answer without learning or putting in any effort themselves.

Comment: @MLeFevre you are right...

Answer (score 3):

would this be your aim? :
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5VnfV/5/)

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="number">6</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
.number{
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: it should be resizable.

Comment: Edited my post. It is now resizible width '.wrapper{width:100%;}

Comment: yes it is now ok.but problem is that each and every time there should be 10 numbers in one row even if resize the window...

Comment: I don't understant. When you resize the window on the fiddle, there are always 10 numbers in a row.